CCS to position an HTML element to the left edge of window without 'absolute' or JS?
On a static website (possible but not desirable to use JS), I've a blog with a column width (on a large screen) of maybe 50% for easy reading.
But then I have a large picture (actually it's an interactive object) with lots of detail that would be great occupying (nearly) the full width of the screen.

width: 100vw; (or w-screen in Tailwind) is great, but the left edge of the picture is in line with the parent. Specifying relative positioning, I can force the picture to the left using Left = -X px, but the distance X varies, so won't work without JavaScript.
Using Tailwind, or vanilla CSS, I've also tried transform: translateY(-25%);, but I still need to calculate the distance.
Absolute positioning is great, but the remainder of the blog doesn't flow around the picture.
Fixed positioning doesn't work either as the picture should scroll with the rest of the text.
So, I think I'm left with Javascript:
document.getElementById("myElementId").style.Left = 
-document.getElementById("myElementId").getBoundingClientRect().left;

Any other ideas? (I would have thought my issue wasn't that unusual, but haven't seen any clean solutions.)

Please see [ask] and take the [tour].  Your question should include a demo snippet with HTML and CSS to show your attempt. It should not include a solution.

Don't forget calc is CSS... (and that is CSS, not CCS ;))

As isherwood said, seeing a runnable snippet goes a long way to understanding what you’re asking. If I’m inferring correctly, though, you’re asking about a breakout layout. There are lots of resources online for how to create those, including SmolCSS, Kevin Powell, Andy Bell, and me.

Noleli, thanks for suggesting the "breakout" term, it describes my goal nicely and is well covered elsewhere, like !(here)[https://smolcss.dev/#smol-breakout-grid]. HOWEVER, after looking at about 25 pages describing all this, learning about clamp, gutter, and also Haolt's great answer, it appeared they all assume I know the main column width, or can change the entire layout to remove all the parent containers or move to CSS grid.
A theme redesign is out of scope for me, unfortunately.

OK, the real, elegant solution is well described at
https://piccalil.li/blog/creating-a-full-bleed-css-utility/
It's called a "Full-Bleed", and is just:
.full-bleed {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
}

Or to leave a bit of margin, try calc(50% - 45vw), and setting your image to width:95vw;

For pure tailwind classes, try:
<img src="myImage"  class="relative  border-4 h-[60vh] ml-[calc(50%-45vw)] w-[90vw]"></img>

Since you stated that you don't always know the width of the content area, you can use this technique (assuming the content area is centered on the viewport).

Set the position of the content area and breakout elements to relative
Set the left property of the breakout element to 50%, which will ensure the left edge is in the center of the content area and screen (for now)
Set the margin-left property of the breakout element to -50vw, which will pull that left edge from the middle of the viewport to the left edge of the viewport
Set the width of the breakout element to 100vw to make sure it stretches across the full screen

This should work regardless of the width of the content area, provided the content area is centered on the viewport, and doesn't rely on calc().


.content-area {
  position: relative;
}
.breakout-element {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  width: 100vw;
}


/* extra demo styles to make it easier to see */
.content-area {
  width: 60%; /* an arbitrary number */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
.breakout-element {
  background: red;
  min-height: 20vh;
}
<div class="content-area">
  <div class="breakout-element"> breakout area</div>
</div>




If you want it to be nearly the full width of the screen, you can use a variable and calc() to subtract a specific width from the margin and width dimensions. Here's an example with 30px of space at the edges, and a different content area width from the original example:


.content-area {
  position: relative;
}
.breakout-element {
  --edge-space: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + var(--edge-space)); /* reduce the distance the left edge is pulled to the left by the distance of the --edge-space variable */
  width: calc(100vw - (2 * var(--edge-space))); /* reduce the width of the breakout element by double the --edge-space variable */
}


/* extra demo styles to make it easier to see */
.content-area {
  width: 35%; /* an arbitrary number */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
.breakout-element {
  background: red;
  min-height: 20vh;
}
<div class="content-area">
  <div class="breakout-element"> breakout area</div>
</div>




You need to know the distance between the image's left edge and screen's left edge, so try putting everything that stand between them to variables and use calc to translate the image.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Put the main column's width, padding left, border left width in variables... */

.column {
  --column-width: 50vw;
  --column-padding: 20px;
  --column-border-width: 1px;
  width: var(--column-width);
  margin: auto;
  padding: var(--column-padding);
  border: var(--column-border-width) solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-indent: 2rem;
}


/* ...and use them to calculate the position of the large object */

.large-obj-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translateX(calc(0px - (100vw - var(--column-width)) / 2 - var(--column-padding) - var(--column-border-width)));
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed #c00;
}

.large-obj {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #7df;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<div class="column">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure excepturi unde cumque ad, ipsa vel dolorum autem omnis praesentium fugiat impedit modi ex nostrum atque hic odit facere eveniet quis!</p>
  <div class="large-obj-wrapper">
    <div class="large-obj">
      <p>Large image or object</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure excepturi unde cumque ad, ipsa vel dolorum autem omnis praesentium fugiat impedit modi ex nostrum atque hic odit facere eveniet quis!</p>




Whoever edited my original question: I find it unhelpful - to the community - to remove my best suggestion, as it could be useful for others, and it certainly had flaws so wasn't a 'true' solution, but was a effective hack or kludge, a quick fix.
So for other's use, another approach is to create a similar item to the 'absolutely positioned' image but put the absolute one at a higher Z-index. 2 lines & pretty clean, works regardless of your current theme, it's just inelegant:
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/851023/pexels-photo-851023.jpeg"  class="absolute left-0 right-0 z-20 mx-auto border-4" style="height:60vh; width:95vw"></img>
<div class="z-10" style="height:60vh;">I am hidden behind the absolute img, but ensure that doesn't hide any more content to follow!</div>

